# chai-as-promised tests don't work with $q promises

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, chai, chai-as-promised

I'm trying to get `chai-as-promised` to work with `$q` promises with karma unit tests.

```
  svc.test = function(foo){
    if (!foo){
      // return Promise.reject(new Error('foo is required'));
      return $q.reject(new Error('foo is required'));
    } else {
      // get data via ajax here
      return $q.resolve({});
    }
  };


  it.only('should error on no foo', function(){
    var resolvedValue = MyServices.test();
    $rootScope.$apply();
    return resolvedValue.should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'foo is required');
  });
```

The unit test just times out. I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here to get the promise to resolve properly. It seems to be an issue with using `$q` -- when I use native `Promise.reject()` it works fine.

I filed a ticket here, but nobody seems to be responding:
https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/issues/150

Answer (score 3):

The way `chai-as-promised` expects to modify promise assertions is [`transferPromiseness` method](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#customizing-output-promises).

> By default, the promises returned by Chai as Promised's assertions are
>   regular Chai assertion objects, extended with a single then method
>   derived from the input promise. To change this behavior, for instance
>   to output a promise with more useful sugar methods such as are found
>   in most promise libraries, you can override
>   chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness.

For Angular 1.3+ support, `$q` promises can be duck-typed by `$$state` property, so native promises won't be affected:

```
chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness = function (assertion, promise) {
  assertion.then = promise.then.bind(promise);

  if (!('$$state' in promise))
    return;

  inject(function ($rootScope) {
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase)
      $rootScope.$digest();
  });
};
```

`chaiAsPromised` chains each asserted promise with `then`. Even if the promise is settled, the rest of the chain still requires the digest to be triggered manually with `$rootScope.$digest()`.

As long as the spec contains no asynchronous code, it becomes synchronous, no promise is required to be returned:

```
it('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
});
```

And is equal to mandatory `$rootScope.$digest()` after each set of `eventually` assertions/expectation when `transferPromiseness` wasn't set:

```
it('...', () => {
  ...
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  expect(...).to.eventually...;
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

Comment: Seems like something that should be provided by a plugin since angular/$q is so common and most companies use chai with it.

Comment: @chovy Sure, why not, the one could create a wrapper package for chai-as-promised that reexports it with listed code (fortunately, it doesn't even have to be forked for that). I've got used to the idea that Mocha/Chai bundle requires setup file any way, it's not a problem for me to have extra several lines there.

Comment: @Willa Right after [`var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised")`](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised#installation-and-setup). If the specs run in Karma or browser environment, it should be placed in a script that is loaded before all specs.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry though I didn't mention that I am running karma using grunt. So all I have is a karma config file. To be precise it is karma mocha & chai

Comment: @Willa You may have something like `files: ['test/setup.js', 'test/*.spec.js']` in Karma config. They are running in specified order, the first one is where the code above should go to.

Comment: Thanks @estus I have found it but it turns out I have to setup requirejs and a bunch other files just to make this work! I guess I will come back to this sometime later.

Comment: It turns out I did not need to use require. Unfortunately it does not work! I am still getting timeouts.

Comment: @Willa I guess it has something to do with your Karma setup rather than with the question. It should work if [`chaiAsPromised.transferPromiseness` was re-assigned before the spec](http://plnkr.co/edit/x6TNFlXtgyr9QkkSq4PK?p=preview). Feel free to open a question if it doesn't work for you for some reason.

Comment: That is what I suspected initially but I made sure it was re-assigned because I console logged that function just immediately using chai-as-promised API and it showed your code meaning it was overridden successfully.

Comment: @Willa It is hard to say what's going wrong. If it is possible to recreate an issue in plunker, this may help.

Comment: @estus thanks for putting up with me buddy. Unfortunately I have to take care of some other thing that will eat up my time. I will try to see if I can reproduce in plunker. Thanks again!

Comment: Where does the `inject()` method come from?
Edit: This comes from ngMock, which I'm not using. "This function is declared ONLY WHEN running tests with jasmine or mocha."  Is there a solution for running e2e tests in production with protractor/CucumberJS?

Comment: @hackel I don't think that this question is specific to chai-as-promised. You need the access to current application's injector, after that you can get $rootScope with `$injector.get('$rootScope')` (that's what `inject` basically does).

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the order of execution in your tests. Asynchronous tasks with chai-as-promised need to happen *before* the expectation.

```
it('does not work', () => {
  $timeout.flush();
  expect(myAsyncTask()).to.eventually.become('foo');
})

it('does work', () => {
  expect(myAsyncTask()).to.eventually.become('foo');
  $timeout.flush();      
})
```

You need to initiate the call to the asynchronous task *before* flushing the queue of asynchronous tasks.

Also, don't use `$rootScope.$digest`. That *may* have other side effects that are not desirable within your test(s).

`$timeout.flush` is what you're looking for.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout

---

To get your specific test(s) working:

```
it('should error on no foo', function(){
  MyServices.test().should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'foo is required')
  $rootScope.$apply();
});

it('should pass on foo', function(){
  MyServices.test('foo').should.eventually.become({});
  $rootScope.$apply();      
}
```

---

**tl;dr**

```
it('async test', () => {
  setup();
  expect();
  execute();
})

it('sync test', () => {
  setup();
  execute();
  expect();
})
```

---

Given the comments posted:

> Should it be mentioned that it is unethical to downvote 'rival' answers on the question you're answering?

Fair enough. I think the answer is misleading, given that there is no extra setup necessary to get chai-as-promised working with Angular without having to deal with the `done` callback. Fwiw, I'll go ahead and try to revoke said downvote and be ethical about it.

> The OP has no signs of timeout in his code and doesn't state that the task is asynchronous. `$rootScope.$digest()` has no side effects in specs when called outside of scope digest. The reason why it is not recommended in production is because it doesn't have the safeguards that `$apply` has.

`$rootScope.$digest` is effectively the same as `$rootScope.$apply` (and `$scope.$apply` for that matter). [source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1073)

`$timeout.flush` will flush non-`$timeout` based functions just as well. It is not exclusive to `$timeout` based functions.

Plunker to showcase how it *just works™*: 
[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4J3oIDSMIG7bfn9svDvq?p=preview)

Comment: The OP has no signs of timeout in his code and doesn't state that the task is asynchronous. `$rootScope.$digest()` has *no* side effects in specs when called outside of scope digest. The reason why it is not recommended in production is because it doesn't have the safeguards that `$apply` has.

Comment: @estus I've tried to answer your concerns to the best of my ability. Also, do check out the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4J3oIDSMIG7bfn9svDvq?p=preview) if you're uncertain as to whether this approach would work or not for 'synchronous' tasks.

Comment: Sure, `$timeout.flush()` works, but it looks like an overkill here, and overkill isn't something that should be done mechanically in specs. If there are unflushed timeouts, the tester may be aware of them and flush them consciously. Otherwise a mere `$rootScope.$digest()` after `eventually` is enough.

Comment: That's essentially what `transferPromiseness` hook does, I've updated the answer to show that the spec is sync with it and [shouldn't return a promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974675/do-i-really-need-to-return-a-promise-in-test-when-using-chai-as-promised). The one may place `$timeout.flush()` instead of `$digest()` into `transferPromiseness` if he/she feels that it fits well, though I wouldn't recommend that for the reasons listed above.